# SQL - How to identify 1 hour time period islands in the given data?

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

The objective is to accept the first complaint received and reject all the complaints received in the 1 hour following the first complaint. For example I have the data below.

| ComplaintID | DateTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/24/2019 1:07 PM |
| 2 | 12/24/2019 1:20 PM |
| 3 | 12/24/2019 1:40 PM |
| 4 | 12/24/2019 2:00 PM |
| 5 | 12/24/2019 2:10 PM |
| 6 | 12/24/2019 2:12 PM |
| 7 | 12/24/2019 2:50 PM |
| 8 | 12/24/2019 2:55 PM |
| 9 | 12/24/2019 3:00 PM |
| 10 | 12/24/2019 3:08 PM |
| 11 | 12/24/2019 4:00 PM |
| 12 | 12/24/2019 4:50 PM |
| 13 | 12/24/2019 7:00 PM |
| 14 | 12/26/2019 7:01 PM |

**Required Output:**

| ComplaintID | DateTime | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/24/2019 1:07 PM | Accept |
| 2 | 12/24/2019 1:20 PM | Reject |
| 3 | 12/24/2019 1:40 PM | Reject |
| 4 | 12/24/2019 2:00 PM | Reject |
| 5 | 12/24/2019 2:10 PM | Accept |
| 6 | 12/24/2019 2:12 PM | Reject |
| 7 | 12/24/2019 2:50 PM | Reject |
| 8 | 12/24/2019 2:55 PM | Reject |
| 9 | 12/24/2019 3:00 PM | Reject |
| 10 | 12/24/2019 3:08 PM | Reject |
| 11 | 12/24/2019 4:00 PM | Accept |
| 12 | 12/24/2019 4:50 PM | Reject |
| 13 | 12/24/2019 7:00 PM | Accept |
| 14 | 12/26/2019 7:01 PM | Accept |

I understand that this would be easy using a programming language, however I need a solution in SQL.

EDIT:

Based on @Gordon's suggestion, I implemented the following recursive query and it works! However, it seems inefficient on large data.

```
with RECURSIVE t AS (
    select row_number as rn,ts, lag(ts,1) over (order by row_number) as baseline from main_table where row_number<3
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    rn+1 as rn 
    ,(select ts from main_table where row_number=rn+1) as ts
    ,case when datediff('hour',ts,baseline)>24 then ts else baseline end as baseline
     from (select * FROM t order by rn desc limit 1 )t where rn<=(select count(*)-1 from main_table)
)

,real_baseline as 
(
select rn,ts,lead(baseline,1) over (order by rn) as real_baseline from t
)

select * 
,case when row_number() over (partition by real_baseline order by ts) =1 then 'Accept'
else 'Reject' end as status
from real_baseline
```

Comment: I think this requires a recursive CTE -- which will not be efficient on a large amount of data.

Comment: When you say "in SQL" do you actually mean pure SQL, or do you just mean it has to happen in the DBMS? Does it have to be a single query, or can it be a procedure? What's the reason for the restriction?

Comment: Procedures/UDFs are fine too.

Comment: sql-server or postgres?

Comment: Have a look a `LAG()` and `LEAD()` analytics SQL functions, and try to find the start of a `session` in your data in order to get your result. [here](https://mode.com/blog/finding-user-sessions-sql/) or [here](https://statsbot.co/blog/event-analytics-define-user-sessions-sql/)

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could apply lead/lag, but not here. The problem with lead/lag being the unpredictable range needed. Likewise a recursive CTE seems to be unworkable as it needs the MIN function in the recursive part; that however is not allowed. Since a function is satisfactory perhaps the best is function returning a table. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=eda6142d352569ddfa0d7e274d22282c).

```
create or replace function public.accept_reject_complaints()
 returns table( o_complaintid integer
              , o_datetime    timestamp 
              , o_status      text
              )
 language plpgsql
AS $$                 
declare
    l_current_end_ts timestamp = '-infinity'::timestamp;

    c_complaint_list cursor for
                     select complaintid, datetime     
                       from complaints
                      order by datetime;
begin
    for complaint_rec in c_complaint_list 
    loop
       if complaint_rec.datetime  > l_current_end_ts then 
          o_status = 'Accept'; 
          l_current_end_ts = complaint_rec.datetime  + interval '1 hour';
       else 
          o_status = 'Reject'; 
       end if; 
   
       o_datetime = complaint_rec.datetime;
       o_complaintid = complaint_rec.complaintid;
       return next; 
    end loop ;

end ; 
$$;
```

Unfortunately since it involves a cursor loop performance will be an issue with large data volumes.

Answer (score 0):

This is Simple Approach .  Truncate each datetime for Hour then in each hour take First or Minimum datetime as accept and other as rejected .

**P.S I have used table_name as complaint change it .tested in Postgresql 8.**

```
SELECT ComplaintID,DateTime,CASE WHEN row_number() over(partition by hour order by 
DateTime)=1 THEN 'Accept' else 'Reject' end as Status from 
(select ComplaintID,DateTime ,date_trunc('hour',DateTime)as hour  from complaint)A ;
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the objective. Please see the required output to understand it better.

Comment: As per your output image 
12/24/2019 1:07 PM Accept 
then 12/24/2019 3:08 PM Reject  

Should be "  Accept "  right since after 2hours of first complain it is  till 3:07 PM from 3:08 it is next hour . 

As per my understanding from first time that hour should begin and every hour in this case begins with like 2:07 , 3:07 pm ,4:07 pm .. ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the continuity of `ComplaintID`, the query is :

```
with recursive cte as (
  select 1 ComplaintID, min(DateTime) DateTime,
    min(DateTime) prev
    from main_table
  union all
  select t2.ComplaintID, t2.DateTime,
    case when t1.prev + interval '1 hour' < t2.DateTime
         then t2.DateTime else t1.prev end
    from cte t1 join main_table t2
    on t1.ComplaintID+1 = t2.ComplaintID
)
select ComplaintID, DateTime,
  case when DateTime=prev
    then 'Accept' else 'Reject' end Status
  from cte
  order by ComplaintID
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qeHgUtyknq4iwt8BwWJK5C/1)

2. Extracting each row that is `Accept`, the query is :

```
with recursive cte as (
  (
    select ComplaintID, DateTime, 'Accept' Status
      from main_table order by DateTime limit 1
  )
  union all
  (
    select t2.ComplaintID, t2.DateTime, 'Accept'
      from cte t1 join main_table t2
      on t1.DateTime + interval '1 hour' < t2.DateTime
      order by t2.DateTime limit 1
  )
)
select t1.ComplaintID, t1.DateTime, coalesce(t2.Status, 'Reject') Status
  from main_table t1 left join cte t2
  on t1.ComplaintID=t2.ComplaintID
  order by t1.ComplaintID
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qeHgUtyknq4iwt8BwWJK5C/0)